# Where does model store data in django?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to define non-database models (Position and Portfolio).

```
# models.py
class Position(models.Model):
    code = None
    price = None
    value = None

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def __init__(self, code, price, value):
        self.code = code
        self.price = price
        self.value = value

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    positions = []

    class Meta:
        managed = False

    def add(self, position):
        self.positions.append(position)


class PositionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Position
        fields = ['code', 'price', 'value']

# serializers.py
class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    positions = PositionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['positions']


# views.py
class PortfolioDetail(APIView):
    """
    List all portfolios, or create a new portfolio.
    """
    def get(self, request, analyzer_id, date, format=None):
        logger.warning('requesting portfolio using {} on {}'.format(analyzer_id, date))
        portfolio = Portfolio()
        portfolio.add(Position('600519', 1900.0, 50000))
        serializer = PortfolioSerializer(portfolio)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

The problem is every time I refresh the page, the position in portfolio will be added. That means there will be **multiple** positions after page refreshing. Why?

Comment: You store these in the `positions` list, so in memory, so as long as you don't restart the server, it will be stored in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store these in the `positions` list of the `Portfolio` class, so in *memory*, so as long as you don't restart the server, it will be stored in memory.

Another problem with this is that as the load increases, typically *multiple* processes run to serve the client(s), and this thus means that if you make two requests, one time it will use the list of *one* process and in another request it will use the other process and hence the other list.

Databases are meant to allow querying in parallel, and to let data persist over multiple runs.

Comment: I still don't understand, I use `portfolio = Portfolio()` and `self.positions.append(position)`, why does it store position in `Portfolio` class rather than the instance?

Comment: I just tried to add __init__ and call `self.positions = []`, then there won't be multiple positions.

Comment: @user1633272: because `self.positions` will first look if there is an attribute at the instance level, if not it will look at the class level, so it will resolve to the `portfolio = []` at the class level that is initialized *once*: when the *class object* is constructed

Comment: So that is a python language issue, not specific to django. Right?

Comment: @user1633272: yes, this is how Python defines its class/data-model.